# Global search DataTable whose columns contain select boxes

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a DataTable (using DataTables 1.10.12) in which all of the columns hold form elements. 3 of the columns contain select boxes. When using the global search box, it works as expected for the columns containing `input` or `textarea` elements but the columns containing select boxes are not properly filtered.

For example, given the below table, if I type "internal" in the search box, I expect the second row to be filtered out because the value in the "Scope" column is not "internal".

However, no rows are filtered out. I realize that this is because the `td` does in fact contain the word "internal" in the form of a non-selected option.

[image]

For filtering these columns, I use functions like this:

```
        /* Create an array with the values of all the select options in a column */
        $.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-select'] = function  ( settings, col )
        {
            return this.api().column( col, {order:'index'} ).nodes().map( function ( td, i ) {
                return $('select', td).val();
            } );
        }
```

How can I force the **global search box** to use this same logic to search the columns that contain select boxes?

I am aware of the ability to add individual column search boxes with custom logic using the search API but I need this to work with the global search not individual columns.

#### [Here is a jsFiddle showing the issue](http://jsfiddle.net/unzjakt0/54/)

Comment: which version of datatables you are using? fiddle resources for datatables is not found.

Comment: @chirag DataTables 1.10.12

Comment: Do you want the table to redraw every time one of the selects change?  i.e. you search for "internal" and the user changes a scope from "internal" to "general".  Does that force a re-draw?

Comment: @BrianKates good question, I hadnt thought about that but now that you mention it, and now that I have the search working, yes I will need to re-apply the search and force a redraw when the selects change. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @annoyingmouse I was able to work out a solution that allows searching for selected values in select boxes while still retaining the normal search functionality for all other columns:

#### [Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oL2uum3L/4/)

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
   function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
      var tdValues=[];
      var $tds=table.row(dataIndex).nodes().to$().find('td');
      $tds.each(function(){
         var $this=$(this);
         var hasSelect=$this.find('select').length >0; // check if current cell has a select box
         var curTdValue= hasSelect ? $this.find('option:selected').text() : $this.text();
         tdValues.push(curTdValue);
      });
      var rowValues=tdValues.join(' ');
      return !!~rowValues.toLowerCase().indexOf(table.search().toLowerCase()); 
   }     
);
```

Comment: Excellent stuff @DelightedD0D, glad I helped. Just wish there was a way I could find to alter the type so that it would work with the native search... ahh well. Well done! :-)

Comment: @annoyingmouse This seems to work as expected, however, from your comments I feel like Im missing a key point here. Admittedly, Im not sure what exactly is happening with `.ext.search.push`. Could you possibly explain what you mean by *alter the type so that it would work with the native search*

Comment: I guess I was looking to replace the type on the column - in much the same way as the plugins in DataTables do - rather than replace the search. It seems as though I, and then you, replaced the search functionality rather than adding a method to it. I do need to scratch my head some more over this though as it took me so long to answer because I was trying different ways of doing it. Hey, if it works then that's gravy... my method isn't as elegant as I'd've hoped though...

Comment: @annoyingmouse gotcha. So far so good but Ill be using this on about 20 different tables so if any drawbacks creep up Ill be sure to come back and mention them

Answer (score 1):

This has had me scratching my head this one :-)

I've come up with this ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/oL2uum3L/)):

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
   function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
      var dataLabel = table
      .row(dataIndex)         //get the row to evaluate    
      .nodes()                //extract the HTML - node() does not support to$     
      .to$()                  //get as jQuery object 
      .find('select')         //find column with data-label
      .val();                 //get the value of data-label
      return !!~dataLabel.toLowerCase().indexOf(table.search().toLowerCase()); 
   }     
);
```

**BUT**, it replaces all other searching and I'm not happy with that. Please don't accept this as the correct answer and wait until someone comes up with something better as I'm sure someone can!

I look forward to seeing a solution!

Comment: You're awesome man, that gave me the start I needed to work out a solution which I have posted here to hopefully help others. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, head scratching over but be warned that this isn't pretty:

```
(function() {
  $.fn.dataTable.ext.type.search.selected = function(data) {
    return !$(data).is("select") ? '' : $(data).val();
  };
})();
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  "columnDefs": [{
    "orderDataType": "dom-select",
    "type": "selected",
    "targets": 2
  }]
});
/* Create an array with the values of all the select options in a column */
$.fn.dataTable.ext.order['dom-select'] = function(settings, col) {
  return this.api().column(col, {
    order: 'index'
  }).nodes().map(function(td, i) {
    return $('select', td).val();
  });
}
$("#example select").on("change", function() {
  var $this = $(this),
    index = null;
  var tableRow = table.row($this.parents('tr'));
  var rowDate = tableRow.data();
  $.each(rowDate, function(k, v) {
    if (v === $this.prop("outerHTML")) {
      index = k;
    }
  });
  var newRowData = rowDate.slice(0);
  var tempSelect = $(newRowData[index]);
  tempSelect.find("option[value!='" + $this.val() + "']").removeAttr("selected");
  tempSelect.find("option[value='" + $this.val() + "']").attr("selected", "selected");
  newRowData[index] = tempSelect.prop("outerHTML");
  table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data(newRowData).draw(true);
});
```

So we keep your sorting function and add a type of `selected` to the relevant column. The `selected` search returns the value of the select but it only returns the value from when the table was initialised.

To get around that we listen to changes on the select inputs within the table, grab the data from the row, copy it, manipulate the copy and replace it in the original position, then we draw the table again. We can then search for the new value.

This keeps the vanilla datatable global search as is but gives it the correct data to search on. Phew!!!!

Hope that helps :-)